# Why does Rust not see a variable after a loop is read?

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings

I have a function, the abbreviated version of which might look like:

```
loop {
    let mut changed = false;
    for p in 0..sys.len() {
        k = ...
        if k == None { continue; }
        // some stuff
        for (v, _) in &key.0 {
           // some stuff
            loop {
                if n == 2 {
                    changed = true;
                } else if n % 2 == 0 {
                    changed = true;
                } else if n >= 2 {
                    changed = true;
                } else {
                    changed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if !changed { return; }
}
```

You can see that flag is accessed in the last if statement. But I get this warning message:

```
warning: value assigned to `changed` is never read
202 |                         changed = true;
    |                         ^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: #[warn(unused_assignments)] on by default
```

And I get no other warning/error messages. Why is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you never exit from the inner loop?

Comment: Pretty smart compiler